# Add roxy file manager plugin to MVC4 Project doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a **MVC project** and in this project i have to use a **wysiwyg** ,so i decided to use **TinyMCE Editor (it's like FCKEditor)** .so i added this editor to my MVC project and everything worked fine .but as you know the **TinyMCE editor** doesn't support upload file so again i have to use another plugin **RoxyFileManager** it is free .

The **RoxyFileManager** contains a lot of files like **JS,css,img,html** and **ashx file for working with files**.

I download these files and when i add this files to an **ASP webform application**  it's works great .but when i added these files to my **MVC4** project it doesn't work !!!?Why ?

I create a folder in **Content folder in MVC(the folder of css and themes)** and when i run my application and call the **Index.htm**(the roxy file manager default page in content folder) it doesn't work ?why?

So as i said these project contain a **ashxfile** i think it because of that but i am not sure or maybe i add these files to a bad location (content location )!!!I said it works with Webform application but not with mvc !!!

So i will be appreciate i give me some help .

Best regards.

http://www.roxyfileman.com/TinyMCE-file-browser